# illegal character in path

Tags: c#

I am trying to get to a file located in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\test software\myapp\demo.exe
```

In VS debugger i see the path as:

```
"\"C:\\\Program Files (x86)\\\test software\\\myapp\\\demo.exe\""
```

when i print it out i see in console :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\test software\myapp\demo.exe"
```

but when i try something like

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(PathMentionedAbove);
```

i get Illegal character in path.

What is wrong? the file exists and path is correct. what's illegal above this path?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

Your path includes " at the beginning and at the end. Drop the quotes, and it'll be ok.

The \" at the beginning and end of what you see in VS Debugger is what tells us that the quotes are literally in the string.

Comment: This is the perfect reason while saving the file during runtime with double quotes inside double quotes. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\test software\myapp\demo.exe";
```

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have the quote marks (`"`) embedded in your string at the start and the end. These are not needed and are illegal characters in a path. How are you initializing the string with the path?

This can be seen from the debugger visualizer, as the string starts with `"\"` and ends with `\""`, it shows that the quotes are part of the string, when they shouldn't be.

You can do two thing - a regular escaped string (using `\`) or a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx) (that starts with a `@`):

```
  string str = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\test software\\myapp\\demo.exe";
```

Or:

```
  string verbatim = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\test software\myapp\demo.exe";
```

Answer (score 6):

The string is surrounded by double quotes.  Yes, that's not a valid character in a path.

You should probably tackle it at the source, but you can strip them out with:

```
        path = path.Replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: @ke3pup Please check this as the answer, since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usualy would enter the path like this ....

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\test software\myapp\demo.exe");
```

Did you register the @ at the beginning of the string? ;-)

Comment: I've tried 
<code>FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@Path); </code> 
but i still get the same problem. I can't do what you're saying since i get the path from else where and store it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

try

"C:/Program Files (x86)/test software/myapp/demo.exe"