# How do I use an illegal character?

Tags: c#

```
public void CreateCertificate()
    {

        File.Create($" 
        {@"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub\" + thisYear + 
        " Certificates- " + certType + "\""}{myFileName}.ppt", 1 , 
        FileOptions.None);
    }
```

So I need the backslash between certype and filename to show it belongs within the folder and not next to. It says its an illegal character but how would I get the file in the folder without it?

Comment: Read about Path.Combine()

Comment: The character `"` _is_ an illegal path character. Check [`Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars) and [`Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [illegal character in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315983/illegal-character-in-path)

Comment: When researching [Path.Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.7.2) you may want to also read about [Environment.GetFolderPath()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: But you're not adding a backslash, you're adding a quote. Replace `"\""` with `"\\"`. But much better would be to use `Path.Combine` and build the string in a more readable fashion.

Comment: Also it seems a little strange to include a string (which uses concatenation) inside `{}`. It would be more readable as: `$@"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub\{thisYear} Certificates- {certType}\{myFileName}.ppt"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code that you wrote the file path that will be generated is (based on my own substitutions for the variables):

```
String thisYear = "2019";
String certType = "UnderGrad";
String myFileName = "myfile";
String fileToCreate = $"{@"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub\" + thisYear + " Certificates- " + certType + "\""}{myFileName}.ppt";

Debug.Print(fileToCreate);
```

Will give you this output:

```
C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub\2019 Certificates- UnderGrad"myfile.ppt
```

If you notice there is a `"` before the filename part of `myfile.ppt` - This is where the Illegal Character comes from.

If you use this code fragment to generate the path:

```
String basePath = @"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub\";
String certificateFolder = $"{thisYear} Certificates- {certType}";
String correctFilePath = Path.Combine(basePath, certificateFolder, $"{myFileName}.ppt");

Debug.Print(correctFilePath);
```

This will result in the output of:

```
C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub\2019 Certificates- UnderGrad\myfile.ppt
```

This version has a `\` where the previous code had a `"` and is no longer illegal, but conforms to the requirement that you wrote the files being in the folder.

**Something else to note:**

You may want to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);` to get the path to the MyDocuments folder of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is that you *cannot* use an illegal character in a path or file name. Otherwise it wouldn't be illegal. :)

But it seems that the problem here is that you though you were adding a backslash (`\`) character, when really you were adding a double quote (`"`) character. So if everything else is ok, you can just replace `"\""` with `"\\"` and it should work.

---

Part of the problem is also that you're doing some strange combination of string interpolation, and it makes the code really hard to read.

Instead you can use just string interpolation to simplify your string (I had to use concatenation below to prevent horizontal scrolling, but you could remove it):

```
string filePath = $@"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub\{thisYear} " + 
                  $@"Certificates- {certType}\{myFileName}.ppt";
```

---

But even better would be to use the `Path.Combine` method, along with some variables, to make the intent very clear:

```
var rootDir = @"C:\Users\Director\Documents\TestCertApp\TestSub"
var fileDir = $"{thisYear} Certificates- {certType}"
var fileName = "{myFileName}.ppt";

var filePath = Path.Combine(rootDir, fileDir, fileName);
```